# WordPress posts can't be linked to a specific category

Tags: wordpress, categories, archive, posts

One of our website has a problem with linking normal posts to a specific category. When we try to link a post to the category named "nieuws" (news), the archive of this category remains empty. Also WordPress shows zero on the categories (taxonomy) page. When I create a new category, for example "nieuws2" everything works as it should be. I've never seen this issue before and it seems to be a bug in the WordPress core. Any idea what this problem could be?

[image]
[image]

Comment: How does it look into the DB? tables wp_posts, wp_terms, wp_term_relationships Anything suspicious there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We figured it out! One of the database rows was crashed. Everything is working as it should be.